# c3.js highlight something specific

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a bar chart and two values x(it goes like 0 5 10 etc.) and y(it goes like 0 1000 2000) Is it possible to highlight the bars that are appearing after 25 on x axis ?

I found chart.focus(targetIds) but I couldn't figure out how to use [it](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar.html).

Answer (score 1):

First things first: there is no function for this.
`Chart.focus(targetId)` is used to highlight one complete set of data and only when the chart has been loaded. It will unhighlight after a mouseover.

Instead you can use a workaround by using groups.
The highlighted and the unhighlighted have to be in different groups with different colors.

The drawbacks: you have twice as columns as before and when you use the tooltip and the legend, then you have to format it or it will be ugly.

But if you're ok with this, here is an example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AkoyaP6618/m72kvrom/)

Comment: Thanks @Akoya ! I think I found a solution but it comes to do point that changing the color to a bright color should be considered as highlighting:

A function can be written to highlight after 25 to use like in the following code (I am going to give the example on index for now):


`color: function (color, d) {
return colors[d.index]
}`

Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUf6a/1/) for more. 
(uncomment the color code).